# Is it possible to get a rounded grouped table style when using the Form view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

The default styling of the `Form` view in SwiftUI is a plain styled table view (when running in an iOS context on iPhone or iPad).

Is it possible to get a rounded grouped style table view, similar to how the iOS setting apps appears?

I tried putting a background view chained after the Form view, but this has no effect.

I saw another suggestion of using an overlay view using a RoundedRectangle view, which does provide a rounded rect styling, but it also covers the Form view with an opaque view obscuring the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no way to change the styling of an actual Form - it seems to ignore modifiers. The best way would be to write your own ListStyle. It could also be achieved by writing a custom Section like view, which probably is the easiest way.